# How do I get the length of an MP3 from my own website?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mp3

I have my own personal website that I've uploaded about 5000 mp3's onto. All I really want to do is be able to look at the mp3 files location and get the files Track Length, preferably in seconds but at this point anything would be nice. I'm just looking for something simple, clean and effective to get just that 1 single piece of information. I've looked around and everything I've found pulls up all kinds of information, but I've not been able to find something that did what I'm looking for. If any of you knows anything that could help, please let me know!

By the way I'm just a hobbyist but I have some experience with PHP, MySQL and Javascript. I would prefer it to be in one of those languages, but if it's simple enough, it can be in just about any language and I'll figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function:

**Code:**

```
<?php
$f = 'somefile.mp3';
$m = new mp3file($f);
$a = $m->get_metadata();

if ($a['Encoding']=='Unknown')
    echo "?";
else if ($a['Encoding']=='VBR')
    print_r($a);
else if ($a['Encoding']=='CBR')
    print_r($a);
unset($a);
?>
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Filesize] => 5108648
    [Encoding] => CBR
    [MPEG version] => 11
    [Layer Description] => 01
    [Protection Bit] => 1
    [Bitrate Index] => 1010
    [Sampling Freq Idx] => 00
    [Padding Bit] => 0
    [Private Bit] => 0
    [Channel Mode] => 01
    [Mode Extension] => 00
    [Copyright] => 0
    [Original Media] => 0
    [Emphasis] => 0
    [Bitrate] => 160
    [Sampling Rate] => 44100
    [Frame Size] => 523
    [Length] => 252
    [Length mm:ss] => 4:12
)
```

Note the `[Length mm:ss] => 4:12` part.

The alternative solution would be to use an external tool like [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [`mp3info`](http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/) along with the built-in function [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec).

**Source:** http://www.zedwood.com/article/127/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually tried that before coming here to ask for help. When I use that all I get is: 
Array ( [Filesize] => 2661030 [Encoding] => VBR )
With the [Filesize] value changing depending on the song name I put in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this one: http://www.binarytides.com/get-play-time-bitrate-mp3-php/
Also if you know the bitrate of the mp3 files you can simply calculate it by getting the filesize of the mp3 file, convert it to bits (or kilobits) and then divide the size by the bitrate. That will give you the time in seconds.